# C# and OpenSSL executable

Tags: c#, parameters, executable

A friend of mine, at work came to me and asked why he can't run that code properly.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            string processExecutable = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\bin\\openssl.exe";

            startInfo.FileName = processExecutable;
            startInfo.Arguments = @"genrsa -out Prvkey.key";

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

when he uses the openSSL.exe, regularly, clicking in the .exe and puts the instructions ***"genrsa -out Prvkey.key"***, it works fine. So its not the instructions itself, but how to pass.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe", "genrsa -out Prvkey.key");
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```